# Sort Codeigniter query results by greatest number of matching tags

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My business database has a column containing a comma separated list of product tag names.

I am trying to get a list of businesses 'similar' to the current business.

My Codeigniter query returns results based upon whether `$tags` from the current business match other businesses in the database.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('business');
$tags = explode (",", $tags);
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $this->db->or_like('tags',$tag);
    }
$this->db->where('business !=',$business);
$this->db->where('active',1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

From this I would like to take this one step further and work out which `$business` has the most similar tags and order the query results accordingly.

So a business with 10 matching tags would be displayed further up a list than a business with only 5 matching tags.

Comment: How are you storing multiple tags in the business table. Comma separated?

Comment: yes, comma separated. I know it's not the best solution, but it's what I have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query executed is logically correct.
You can check your executed query with `$this->db->last_query();`.
I think your query is logically wrong.
Try like this.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('business');
$tags = explode (",", $tags);
foreach($tags as $key => $tag) {
    if ($key == 0){
        $this->db->group_start();
    } 
    $this->db->or_like('tags', $tag);
    if ($key == count($tags)-1) {
        $this->db->group_end();
    }
}
$this->db->where('business !=', $business);
$this->db->where('active', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Hi, this doesb't seem to list the businesses in order of greatest number of matching tags.